# Trigger in one column should update the value of another column in different tabels

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm beginner in sql. I use sql server management studio 2008 R2 and I need help.
I have two tables

tblProject

```
 ProjectID   BeginDate       EndDate
     1.      2013-03-20      2013-03-30
     2.      2013-04-10      ........
     3.      2014-03-10      .....
```

tblProjectMembers

```
     MemberID    ProjectID    MemberSince    MemberUntil
     1.          1            2013-03-20     2013-03-30
     2.           ....        ..........     ..........
```

I want to create a trigger on EndDate column, so when tblProject.EndDate is inserted, trigger should update the column MemberUntil and break membership for existing members. (Note: some members can leave the project earlier, before end date..but some of them are there until the end od project).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only want to act on the first time the `EndDate` is changed from being `NULL` to non-`NULL`, the trigger would be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_tblProject_U
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE
        pm
    SET
        MemberUntil = i.EndDate
    FROM
        inserted i
             inner join
        deleted d
             on
                 i.ProjectID = d.ProjectID and
                 i.EndDate is not null and
                 d.EndDate is null
             inner join
        tblProjectMember pm
             on
                 i.ProjectID = pm.ProjectID
    WHERE
        pm.MemberUntil is null
```

If you have additional logic you want to apply, such as if `EndDate` is set to `NULL` again or is updated to a different value, the trigger may have to become more complex.

For information on `inserted` and `deleted`, please see [Use the inserted and deleted Tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191300.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
create or replace trigger xyz
after insert of EndDate on tblProject for each row
begin
    update tblProjectMembers set
    MemberUntil = (select :new.EndDate from tblProject where tblProjectMembers.ProjectID = tblProject.ProjectID);

    exception when others then
null;

end;
/
```

Comment: question is tagged [tag:sql-server]. SQL Server triggers run once per statement, there's no `for each row` option. It also cannot target individual columns.